# Mostrar Mensaje de Error si un String contiene un caracter numerico

Tags: string, java-swing, excepciones

Pues esa es mi pregunta, estoy haciendo un formulario en java swing y a la hora de rellenar los campos del JTextField quiero lanzar una ventana de error en el caso de que contenga algún carácter numérico. He estado probando muchas cosas pero no he llegado a nada. Actualmente me quedo pillado aquí:

```
        if (labor.isEditable()) { //Este if es porque dependiendo del usuario
        try { //que introduzca, habrá casillas en las que pueda escribir o no
            Integer.parseInt(labor.getText().toString()); //En el caso de que esto lance una excepción significara que la conversión no se ha realizado y por tanto es un String
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La labor NO PUEDE tener contenido numerico");
            labor.setText(""); //Pongo en blanco el campo del JTextField
            valido = false;

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            valido = true; //Verifico de que el contenido es correcto

        }
    }
```

He estado haciendo pruebas y hay veces que si me lo detecta y me muestra el mensaje de error en estos casos:

- Si pongo un String que comience por un numero: Ej ==> "43sgfdlgfd"
- Si pongo un numero. Ej ==> "32214" , "23532"...

Pero no consigo que funcione en el caso de que comience por una letra y contenga algún carácter numérico por el medio en plan Labor ==> "Limpiar los Cr124istales".

Alguna idea de como puedo hacer???

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar el método [String.matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) que compara la cadena con una expresión regular

```
if(test.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
// error, contiene un dígito
}
```

En este caso `".*\\d.*"` es una expresión regular que especifica cualquier cadena de texto que contenga un digito.

Comment: Perfecto muchísimas gracias funciona ya a las mil maravillas :))